# bootstrap text inside div always at the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML using bootstrap in my code.

```
<div class="row-fluid image_div">
        <h4 class="text-center"><a href="/category">name_of_item</a></h4>
         <a target="_blank" href="link_for_item">
            <img class="item-size" src="photo.url" alt="name_of_item"/>
        </a>
        <p> quick_summary </p>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <span class="pull-right"><b class="price">£ price </b></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid bottom">
            <a class="btn btn-small btn-warning pull-left" href="/user">Add To Wish List</a>
            <a target="_blank" 
               class="btn btn-info pull-right" 
               href="link_for_item">
                Check It Out
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i have the top div (image_div) height defined as below

```
    .image_div{
    height: 450px;
     }
```

In the above code, i want the inside div with "bottom" class to always to stay at the bottom of the top div (image_div). Please suggest, how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the proper solution would be to position the `bottom` div absolute. Something like this:

```
.bottom {    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You will also have to set the `position` of the `image_div` to `relative` to make it work, as the position absolute needs to know what it should use as a reference for positioning.

There are properties like vertical-align: bottom, but I would advise against them as they require you to use display: table-cell and/or other ugly css.

**edit:**
To make the price appear to the top I would change this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <span class="pull-right"><b class="price">£ price </b></span>
</div>
```

into this:

```
<span class="price">£ price </span>
```

and then position it absolute in the same way:

```
.price {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: block:
}
```

I am also pretty sure the `.row-fluid` on the bottom div is not required.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also let me know how i can make div element with span of price always to be close to (top of) div of bottom without any space because of moving bottom to absolute 0 ?

Comment: The absolute property on price is making it to be on top of top level div (image_div). I would like it the price to be on top of bottom div and the price to be shown on the right side. I have removed the row-fluid on the span element as well. Could you suggest ?

Comment: move it inside the bottom div then, and add the `right` property to the css (see edit)